# Integral operator convergence study in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

#### Exercise

I want to study in $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ the convergence of
$$A_nf(x)=\log n \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{1+n(x-y)^2}f(y)dy. $$

#### Solving

**a)** Pointwise convergence :

For $n \to \infty$ it's easy to see that $A_n\to A=0$ pointwise

**b)** Strong convergence

I want to show $\|(A_n-A)f\|^2\to 0$ that is $\|A_nf\|^2\to0$. Using
Young's inequality ,
if  $f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $ f(x)^2\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Changing variables with $z=\sqrt{n}t$,
$$\|A_nf\|_2=\|f*K_n\|_2\le \frac {\log n}{n^{1/2}}\,\|f\|_2\|K\|_1\to0, $$
where $K_n= \frac{1}{1+nt^2}$ and $K= \frac{1}{1+z^2}$.

**c)** Uniform convergence

Is the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality useful? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already shown that
$$
\|A_nf\|_2\leq\frac {\|K\|_1\,\log n}{\sqrt n}\, \|f\|_2,
$$
which says that 
 $$
\|A_n\|\leq\frac {\|K\|_1\,\log n}{\sqrt n}.
$$

Comment: ok it was my tought, but I didn't know if it was correct ;) thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. No need for this answer in particular, but please consider upvoting answers that you find useful; that's how this site works.